# Не могу поставить gsl gem

Tags: gems, c, ruby, linux

Здравствуйте,

Пытаюсь поставить [GSL gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/gsl) но на моменте компиляции С библиотеке rvm вылетает *make failed, exit code 2*, посмотрев в интернете понял что не тока у меня проблема...
Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379729/problems-installing-gsl-gem) советуют поставить GSL 1.14, мне не помогло (также пробовал 1.15 и 1.16 c deval и без), пробовал на debain 6 и 7 на ubuntu и arch.

Полная ошибка [pastebin.com/dhP6UTww](http://pastebin.com/dhP6UTww)

В итоге нашел [форк](https://github.com/blackwinter/rb-gsl) который должен работать он встал даже с rubygems (gem install rb-gsl) но он тоже не работает:

```
_[1] pry(main)> require 'rb-gsl'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rb-gsl
from /home/y/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'_
```

Comment: С gsl в принципе понятно он на Ruby 2x не работает, на 1,9 встал. Теперь нужно понять почему rb-gsl не работает.

Comment: Проблема в 2.1 на него не встает gsl, под 2.0 встал с gsl 1.15, а вот форк так и не работает что в принципе не страшна

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делайте

```
require 'rbgsl'
```

или даже просто

```
require 'gsl'
```

По идее форк Ruby 2.x совместим. В строчке с ошибкой:

```
vector_source.c:676:37: error: assignment of read-only member ‘klass’
```

не вижу никаких явных намёков на присвоение klass'у:

```
rb_class2name(CLASS_OF(obj)));
```

Comment: Да действительно если делать require 'rbgsl' то все хорошо, спасибо!

[1] pry(main)> require 'rbgsl'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> require 'gsl'
=> true
[3] pry(main)>